# Input range with CSS: how to display in the right position the ticks

Tags: html, css, input, blazor

I'm creating with Blazor a component to display a Slider using `input type="range"`. The main issue is how to display the `datalist`. Using CSS I have this result

[image]

```css
/*********** Baseline, reset styles ***********/
input[type="range"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}

    /* Removes default focus */
    input[type="range"]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    /******** Chrome, Safari, Opera and Edge Chromium styles ********/
    /* slider track */
    input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
        background-color: #add8e6;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        height: 0.5rem;
    }

    /* slider thumb */
    input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
        appearance: none;
        margin-top: -4px; /* Centers thumb on the track */
        background-color: #808080;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        height: 1rem;
        width: 1rem;
    }

    input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
        outline: 3px solid #808080;
        outline-offset: 0.125rem;
    }

    /*********** Firefox styles ***********/
    /* slider track */
    input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
        background-color: #add8e6;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        height: 0.5rem;
    }

    /* slider thumb */
    input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
        background-color: #808080;
        border: none; /*Removes extra border that FF applies*/
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        height: 1rem;
        width: 1rem;
    }

    input[type="range"]:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
        outline: 3px solid #808080;
        outline-offset: 0.125rem;
    }

    input[type="range"] + datalist {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-top: -23px;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }

        input[type="range"] + datalist option {
            width: 2ex;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 42px;
            align-items: end;
            background-image: url(tick.png);
            height: 4ex;
            background-position-y: -15px;
            background-position-x: center;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        /* option active styles */
            input[type="range"] + datalist option:hover,
            input[type="range"] + datalist option:focus {
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #036;
                outline: 0 none;
            }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="sld1" class="form-control" min="1" max="5" list="sld1_list">
<datalist id="sld1_list" style="--list-length: 6;">
<option value="1" label="One"></option>
<option value="2" label="Two"></option>
<option value="3" label="Three"></option>
<option value="4" label="Four"></option>
<option value="5" label="Five"></option>
<option value="6" label="Six"></option>
</datalist>
```

If I change the number of items in the `datalist`, the label is completely out of sync with the slider (run the code for an example).

Is there a way to display the `datalist` using only CSS regardless of the number of items in the it?

Or in the Blazor point of view, how can I create or how can I write a function in order to have a `div` that contains all the values and be responsive at the some time?

Comment: In the example the CSS places the label in a precise position because I know the exact number of labels. Generally speaking, how can I change the CSS for an unknown number of lables?

Comment: It all depends on how much css you would have to change, but you can dynamically assign inline css (ex: `style="--list-length: @optionNumber"`).

Comment: When you say "unknown", do you mean dynamic or that you don't want to bother know how much labels there are and just separate them evenly?

Comment: To display the labels, I have to change the CSS `input[type="range"] + datalist option` to position the labels. How can I have a generic CSS that takes into account the `--list-length` and display the label in the right position? Also, they should be responsive: so, if the size of the range is small, some labels have to not be displayed.